# Can't install radeon crimson 15.12 drivers Kali Linux

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, ati, amd, fglrx

I recently installed Kali GNU/Linux Rolling but I cant install my graphics drivers, I followed this [link](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64#)

Got a few errors along the way but this one remains unsolved.
This shows up when I press the install button:

```
cat /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log 
Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers for
greater than 3.6 release.
/lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64/build/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.
```

but `uname -r` tells me I have 4.6.0-kali1-amd64, hence my confusion.

Comment: Have you installed the kernel headers? If you haven't, try: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: @iñakimurillo That returns the following:


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64'

Answer (score 1):

You have to add to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file ([source](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Then update repositories and install headers:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, im still getting the same problem. :(
If you have more advices I'll happily try them

Comment: Did you manage to install the linux headers successfuly?

Comment: Yes @Iñaki Murillo they were installed successfully but im getting the same error. I also updated but that didnt help